# Parameter count mismatch on startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, startup

I'm getting a parameter count mismatch except right after the Startup.cs code has finished executing. If fails on exit of the Startup class. But I can't figure out where the code goes next. It doesnt go to my controller.

```
 public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var container = SimpleInjectorInitializer.Initialize(app);
            ConfigureAuth(app, container);
        }
    }
```

Startup.Auth

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app, Container container)
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => container.GetInstance<ApplicationUserManager>());
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
            app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
        }
    }
```

Stack trace:

```
[TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +11414282
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +54
   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +21
   WebActivator.BaseActivationMethodAttribute.InvokeMethod() +236
   WebActivator.ActivationManager.RunActivationMethods() +370
   WebActivator.ActivationManager.RunPostStartMethods() +41
   WebActivator.StartMethodCallingModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +125
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +534
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +352
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): Parameter count mismatch.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9947380
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +261
```

I've just finished registering my ASP.NET.Identity managers and then I receive this error.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Please show the definition of the `PostApplicationStartMethodAttribute`s that you use in your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple injector remove the WebActivator Assembly

```
namespace WebApplication1.App_Start
{
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    using SimpleInjector;
    using SimpleInjector.Extensions;
    using SimpleInjector.Integration.Web;
    using SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.Mvc;
    using Owin;
    using Models;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
    using Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
    using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
    using SimpleInjector.Advanced;
    using Microsoft.Owin;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public static class SimpleInjectorInitializer
    {
    }
```

It wants to look like the above code

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood of your injector it is called

```
System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
```

with two arguments, the first being the target instance on which the method is called and second being the array of method arguments.

We don't know your context but the problem comes from the array of method arguments. The mismatch is happening there. There is parameter count mismatch.

Use debug and see where this happen and fix it, depending on your context.

Comment: I found out that the WebActivator source code was being called which caused this issue. It needs to be removed

Comment: @AndrewKilburn ok Invoke it properly depending on your parameters or just remove it.

Comment: I removed it as I actually missed the part which told me to remove it in the tutorial as it isnt needed

Comment: @AndrewKilburn Okay, if the answer help you, you can mark it as corrected.